# RewriteRule with two get parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, get

I have a folder/file structure like this:

```
www.example.com/a/<optional subfolder>/file.png
```

and I want to have a RewriteRule that passes the "a" as the first parameter and all the stuff after that  (file.png or subfolders/file.png) to a file called file.php, so if a user visits

```
www.example.com/a/file.png (this is not an actual file path, it's somewhere else)
```

it should be rewritten to

```
www.example.com/file.php?user=a&file=file.png
```

and

```
www.example.com/a/random/subfolders/here/file.png
```

will be rewritten to

```
www.example.com/file.php?user=a&file=random/subfolders/here/file.png
```

I tried a whole lot of RewriteRules I found on the Internet, one of them even worked but not for subfolders. As I do not know one thing about RegEx, I'd really appreciate your help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this rule to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /file.php?user=$1&file=$2 [L,QSA]
```